# get the specific data from JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to get a specific data from my JSON API but I always get `undefine` in my console.

Here is my TS file where I use `http get` to get my JSON API:

My TS code:

```
this.http.get('http://xxxxx.com/xxx/api.php/customer?filter=customer.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.customer = data.customer;
            console.log(this.customer);
            this.cus_city = this.customer.customer_delivery_city_address;
            console.log("City Address: " +this.cus_city)
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Something went wrong.");
        });
```

Here is the API result in my console:

[image]

What I wanted to get is the `customer_delivery_city_address`[image]. I tried to pass the `this.customer.customer_delivery_city_address` to `this.cus_city` variable and show it to my console `console.log("City Address: " +this.cus_city)` but I am getting `undefined` result. All is well when I call it to my HTML `{{customer.customer_delivery_city_address}}`. I still have no idea how can I get the specific data to my TS file. Hope anyone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: angular1 or angular2?

Comment: try this.customer[0].customer_delivery_city_address

Comment: I'm using angular2.

Comment: thank you very much @JayDeeEss, it worked from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.customer` is an array not an object. access the `customer_delivery_city_address` property by index.

```
this.cus_city = this.customer[0].customer_delivery_city_address;
console.log("City Address: " +this.cus_city)
```

Comment: @Patrick nice make sure to check this as an answer if this helped

Answer (score 2):

I think the response which is coming is an array. You should try this:

```
this.customer[0].customer_delivery_city_address
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way.

```
customer: any;

getCustomer() {
return this.http.get('url').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

loadCustomer(){
this.customer = [];

this.getCustomer().subscribe(d => {
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
   this.customer.push(d[i]);
  }
}, err => {console.log(err)})
}
```

//in view

```
<div *ngFor="let c of customer">
{{c.customer_delivery_city_address}}
</div>
```

You are tring to do **this.customer.customer_delivery_city_address** when **this.customer** is an array, if you want the first element out you can do **this.customer = data.customer[0]**.

```
<div>
{{customer.customer_delivery_city_address}}
</div>
```